# Keep Visual Studio from building ClickOnce files

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build, clickonce, compilation

I'm working on a Windows service using Topshelf. I accidentally published the project once and now with every compilation the ClickOnce installer is generated. This makes no sense for this project. How can I revert that?